# Javascript DOM extend text selection one word in both directions

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Assuming a user has selected some text on the page, i want to extend the selection within my code to include one word from last and end both. I have tried the following:

```
selection.modify('move', 'forward', 'word');
selection.modify('move', 'forward', 'word');
selection.extend(endNode, endOffset);
selection.modify('extend', 'backward', 'word');
selection.modify('extend', 'backward', 'word');
```

But looks like it doesnt pick up the adjacent sibling nodes. It makes no difference. Can someone help me out on this one.

Comment: It doesnt pick up the adjacent sibling nodes. It makes no difference